# Trying to focus on a specific div on click of an anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I am trying to get focus on a specific div on click of an anchor link.
  Here is the code

```
<a href="somepage.html#divname">Link</a>
```

I am facing a problem that the view is rendered from different partial views like header footer etc. 
The header contains the link to a particular div from another view and it has a sticky navbar. When I click the link on nav bar it does focus on the div. But some part of div hides behind the header navbar. 
Which looks clumsy according to the UI perspective. 
Here is the navbar code:

```
  <nav><li><a href="somepage.html#divname">Link</a></li></nav>
```

The example code for page div could be something like

```
  <div id="divname">Some Content</div>
```

Please give me a clue how can I get the div to show just beneath the sticky menu bar.

Comment: You could add a padding-top to the `#divname` with a value equal to the height of the navbar, so the text will be immediately visible.

Comment: If you want to do it with only css and html you could give a padding-top to the div equal to height of the navbar as mentioned in above comment. Otherwise you can use js to achieve this by scrollTop

Comment: Padding top renders it to create some extra space. Which does not reset. I think its not a good way.

Comment: Can you please show me some example code to make it scroll top to a certain percentage. Padding top does not return good results.

Answer (score 0):

Try with giving some margin-top to the div you want to focus on clicking, so that, the navbar will not hide your div and then change your href from

```
href="somepage.html#divname"
```

to

```
href="#divname"
```

only. Always give unique ids or classes to the elements in HTML so that the machine will not get confused between them and treat two different elements the same way. Hope this will work for you. If not post a response for help.

Comment: I have tried margin-top but that also does create a space between the elements which is awe full. I want a comprehensive use case handle on this.

Comment: dont give alot of margin try "margin-top: 105px;" or accordingly so that it will not ruin your ui

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of questions like this one on StackOverflow. Try this one for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59380086/1973005

> You can add a pseudo-element (::before) to the linked element in CSS, using the following settings. This creates an invisible block above the linked element which again creates an offset for the linked element position, since the top of that pseudo-element will actually be the position of the link anchor.

```
.anchor_offset::before {
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  height: 10em; // Whatever height your navbar is
  margin-top: -10em; // Whatever height your navbar is
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```
<div id="divname" class="anchor_offset">Some Content</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't address my question comprehensively.

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe I can still help you.

Comment: As I said in the previous answer. setting padding and margin top only creates a space which is unwanted. Can you please show me a code example of Javascript ScrollTop() if you might know about it.